# (Post polls tutorial) Django admin: After adding new related model type (free response, true/false, etc.), how to add to Django admin

Tags: django, django-models, admin

I just finished the Django polls tutorial. In the tutorial, you essentially build a multiple choice question (a question with related choices). You then configure the admin such that you get this really nice "ADD CHOICE" button. (I love Django so far)

I want to build a quiz app that has other question types too, such as free-response, true/false, etc, and collect the series of different question under a new model called Quiz. I eventually want to get a button "SELECT QUESTION TYPE" in Django admin, but how would I do this?

Here's my attempt at my models:

```
(models.py)

class Quiz(models.Model):
    quiz_name = models.CharField

class Multiple_choice_question(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz)
    question_text = models.CharField    

class Free_response_question(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz)
    question_text = models.CharField

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Multiple_choice_question)
    choice_text = models.CharField
```

In my models above, Multiple_choice_question and Free_response_question are identical except for the fact that Multiple_choice_question has children (choices) and Free_response_question does not, but I will be creating many different problem types, with many different attributes other than question_text: for example I'll have questions with/without images, others with attributes such as "x-component" and "y-component" for drawing vectors as the question, etc., so I don't just want to use the same model for all question types because all of the attributes would show up in the admin every time.

I want the flow to be:

Log in to the admin ---> Select a quiz, or click "ADD A NEW QUIZ" ---> Once a quiz has been created, there should be a button "SELECT QUESTION TYPE" ---> Upon selecting a problem type, it should populate the attributes of that question type, which I would fill in and save (or add another question type).

Here's the admin.py code that the tutorial left me with... how would I modify it to achieve what I want?

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Choice, Question

class ChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Choice
    extra = 3

class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None,               {'fields': ['question_text']}),
        ('Date information', {'fields': ['pub_date'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
    ]
    inlines = [ChoiceInline]
    list_display = ('question_text', 'pub_date', 'was_published_recently')
    list_filter = ['pub_date']
    search_fields = ['question_text']

admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```

Here is my attempt at editing it, but what else do I need to do?

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Quiz, Multiple_choice_question, Free_response_question, Choice

class ChoiceInLine(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Choice    

class MultipleChoiceQuestionInLine(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Multiple_choice_question
    inlines = [ChoiceInLine]

class FreeResponseQuestionInLine(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Free_response_question

class QuizAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = *Choice of* [MultipleChoiceQuestionInLine, FreeResponseQuestionInLine, etc.]

admin.site.register(FreeResponseQuestionInLine, FreeResponseQuestionInLine, Quiz, QuizAdmin)
```

Thanks ahead of time, and any other suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OH, this could be a big question.

OK, Follow your question, when you choose some "Question Type", there are some different attributes display on the page. FOR resolve this problem, you need several steps to do.

1. use AJAX, Javascript OR JQuery TECH to get the user's choice from the Template page, then send a request(post / get) to a special method(For Example, /admin/get_choice)
2. set up a url for this method(url(r'^/admin/get_choice/$', get_choice)).
3. In method get_choice, get the parameter as an option to search results from the database, then return the results back to the Template page.
4. At the Template Page, use AJAX, Javascript OR JQuery TECH to display the results on the Template page.
5. POST everything to a method to SAVE the results into the database.
6. FINISHED.

I hope this can give you some advises.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This appears more complicated than I was hoping. I was hoping there was some built-in functionality for dealing with selecting from multiple related object models, but I guess not everything is easy...

Comment: Yes, it is. Django is only a framework. It just put everything together, and give you the very common way to use it. If you have some special functions, especially the effects of pages, you have to develop them by yourself.